# How can I get values from a complex Json object?

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to get values from Json objects that all are formed like this one: 
http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=4798

I tried several libraries but none of them resulted in the way I wanted. I want to put the values into specific Datamembers.

This was my last attempt, it runs but it seems like my Datamembers are not getting any values.

```
namespace JSON_Data
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string jsonString = @"{""item"":{""icon"":""http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4996_obj_sprite.gif?id=4798"",""icon_large"":""http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4996_obj_big.gif?id=4798"",""id"":4798,""type"":""Ammo"",""typeIcon"":""http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo"",""name"":""Adamant brutal"",""description"":""Blunt adamantite arrow...ouch"",""current"":{""trend"":""neutral"",""price"":305},""today"":{""trend"":""neutral"",""price"":0},""members"":""true"",""day30"":{""trend"":""positive"",""change"":""+2.0%""},""day90"":{""trend"":""positive"",""change"":""+8.0%""},""day180"":{""trend"":""positive"",""change"":""+23.0%""}}}";

            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Item));
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
            Item obj = (Item)ser.ReadObject(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how my class "Item" looks

```
namespace JSON_Data
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Item
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Icon_large { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Members { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just paste your source json in a converter like [this one](http://json2csharp.com/) (First result on Google). Your properties name are not the same as those in the Json, that's why it's not working.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault, Many thanks for answering so quickly! I'm on it now.

Comment: i noticed the string has some extra properties value which your item class does not have.  so simply  Deserilization can not return the object. ur input seems wrong to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can try the **Newtonsoft** i can provide a way.. its very good and better approach as far as i think

```
var ob = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
Item a = ((JObject)ob["item"]).ToObject<Item>();
```

Comment: thanks alot! This is what I had in mind, It works really well with all Json files i wanted to. I tried working with Newtonsoft during this project but I jist did one little thing different that made it not work.

Comment: no problem.  I'm glad that resolved the issue. Go Ahead. and enjoy code/knowledge sharing.  Happy Coding.

Answer (score -1):

There are several JSON serializers you can use in C#. Some have better performance, some have better fault tolerance and others have circular reference treatments.

In your case, I see that you simply want an object without passing it (to a WCF) anywhere. You can follow the second answer of this question: [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9326146/3481183) Example code copied from that answer:

```
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ 'Name': 'Jon Smith', 'Address': { 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY' }, 'Age': 42 }");

string name = stuff.Name;
string address = stuff.Address.City;
```

A dynamic object in C# allows you to read a property without declaring a class for it.